# quickest way in R to check that all columns are identical

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix with 3 columns

```
10             10                       10
8              8                        8
9              9                        9
7              7                        7
5              5                        5
4              4                        4
3              3                        3
6              6                        6
2              2                        2
1              1                        1
```

What would be the fastest way to check that all the columns are identical? I can do something like `all` or `identical` to check any two and then keep collapsing with the next set but is there anything more clever?

Ideally, I would like a solution that is independent of the number of columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try:

```
 all(m1[,1]==m1)
 # [1] TRUE
 all(m2[,1]==m2)
 #[1] FALSE
```

#### data

```
 m1 <- matrix(c(10:1, 10:1, 10:1), ncol=3)
 m2 <- cbind(m1, 11:2)
```

Comment: In case the question requires knowing which rows are identical and which not, do this instead: `rowSums(m[,1]==m1) == ncol(m1)`

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps

```
 all(duplicated(t(m))[-1])
```

will work.  This transposes the matrix (since `duplicated` works row-wise), and then checks that every row except the first is a duplicate of an earlier row.

@akrun's answer is probably marginally faster.  Both answers rely on knowing something about row/column structure: in @akrun's case, that matrices are stored in column-major order (so replicating the first column to match the length of the full unpacked matrix will work), and in my case that `duplicated` works row-wise.

If you wanted to avoid that knowledge you could use

```
all(sweep(m,MARGIN=1,STATS=m[,1],FUN="=="))
```

(do an element-wise comparison of each column with the corresponding element of `m[,1]`, then see if all the comparisons are true)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the rankMatrix function to determine how many linearly independent columns you had. In the case of all being identical the result, should be 1.

```
require(Matrix)  # now a recommended package so it ships with R
m <- matrix(10:1, 10,3)
rankMatrix(m)==1
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `MARGIN` argument in `unique` to get only unique columns in your matrix:

```
ncol(unique(m, MARGIN = 2)) == 1L
```

---

As far as "quickest" here are the results on my machine:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  all(m[,1]==m),
  all(duplicated(t(m))[-1]),
  ncol(unique(m, MARGIN = 2)) == 1L,
  Matrix::rankMatrix(m) == 1L,
  times = 5000L
)

Unit: nanoseconds
                              expr   min    lq      mean median     uq     max neval  cld
                  all(m[, 1] == m)   900  1600   2383.40   2000   2500   44900  5000 a   
         all(duplicated(t(m))[-1]) 28000 33800  47087.68  38200  45650 5065500  5000  b  
 ncol(unique(m, MARGIN = 2)) == 1L 31800 37800  52746.86  43300  52100 4444300  5000   c 
       Matrix::rankMatrix(m) == 1L 62500 76300 105550.94  81500 103800 5107700  5000    d
```